# Use of Enable blocking in PDI - Pig Script Executor

Tags: apache-pig, pentaho, pdi

I am exploring Big data plugin in Pentaho 5.2. I was trying to run `Pig Script` executor. I am unable to understand the usage of 
`Enabling Blocking`. The PDI documentation says that

> If checked, the Pig Script Executor job entry will prevent downstream
>   entries from executing until the script has finished processing.

I am aware that running a pig script will convert the execution to Map reduce jobs. I am running the job with `Start job -> Pig Script`. If I disable the `Enable blocking step` I am unable to execute the script. I am getting permission denied errors. As per the documentation " ".

What does downstream mean here. I do not pass any hops from the pig script out. I am unable to understand the `Enable blocking step`. Any hints can be helpful and will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable blocking: the task is deployed to the Hadoop cluster; PDI will follow up on progress and only proceed with the rest of the job tasks AFTER the execution of the Hadoop job finishes;

Enable blocking is disabled: PDI deploys the task to the Hadoop cluster and forgets about it. The rest of the job tasks proceed immediately after the cluster accepts the task, but doesn't wait for it to complete.